# Build Storm Trident topology and persist tuples in HBase , but there's no data in hbase

Tags: hbase, apache-storm, topology, trident

I build a storm trident topology like this:

```java
tridentTopology.newStream(spoutId, spout).parallelismHint(spoutParallel)
                       .each(new Fields("tId", "message"), new VerifyFilter())
                       .each(new Fields("tId", "message"), new ParseFunction(), new Fields("rowKey", "column", "value"))
                       .groupBy(new Fields("rowKey", "column"))
                       .aggregate(new Fields("value"),new Count(),new Fields("count"))
                       .each(new Fields("rowKey", "column", "count"), new SaveFunction(), new Fields(columns))
                       .shuffle()
                       .partitionPersist(factory, new Fields(rowKeyANdColumns), new HBaseUpdater())
                       .parallelismHint(boltParallel);
```

util execute `each(new Fields("rowKey", "column", "count"), new SaveFunction(), new Fields(columns)`, I got print log in SaveFunction,
but partitionPersist not wirte date into hbase, and no error in all topology;

Who can give some suggestions?

Comment: What is `new Fields(columns)`? Is `columns` are variable? What is its content?

Comment: columns is constant : private static final String[] columns = new String[]{"d0","d1","d2","d3","d4","d5","d6","d7"};  SaveFunction will generate 8 output field  {"d0","d1","d2","d3","d4","d5","d6","d7"}.

Comment: I assume `rowKeyANdColumns` is  `private static final String[]` with `{"rowKey", "d0","d1","d2","d3","d4","d5","d6","d7"}`. `factory` is `HBaseState`? What is the code of `SaveFunction`?

Comment: yes,and SaveFunction only for **generateValues** as: `@Override 
    public void execute(TridentTuple tuple, TridentCollector collector) {collector.emit(generateValues(tuple.getString(0),Integer.valueOf(tuple.getString(1)), tuple.getLong(2)));
    }Values generateValues(String rowKey, int diff, long count) {
        Values values = new Values();
        for ( int i = 0; i <= 7; i++ ) {
            if ( i == diff ) {
                values.add(i, count);
            } else {
                values.add(i, 0);
            }
        }
        values.add(8, rowKey);
        return values;
    }`